# Mousekeys with External Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse-keys

I'm on a Macbook Pro with OS X 10.9.3.

Mousekeys works fine on the builtin keyboard but seems to have no effect on an external keyboard. How can I change this behavior?

The external keyboard has no numpad.

Comment: Did you try the numeric keypad on the external keyboard?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the external keypad has no numpad.

Comment: Thats pretty important. If thats the case, if there is no function button to supplement a numeric keypad then 8,I,U,O may not work...

Comment: I don't think you are able to do this without a numeric keypad mapped on your keyboard. The only way to override this is to remap those shortcuts. This may be useful to you: http://superuser.com/questions/359570/how-to-map-keyboard-to-mouse-buttons-in-os-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks 13ruce1337, KeyRemap4MacBook did the job and I get to use hjkl!

The description of cmd + S + D and then holding S + D sounds very awkward in words but in practice it feels reasonable if you just want to click a single item. "High Speed Mode" is a nice convenience.

[image: KeyRemap4MacBook]