# External keyboard doesn't show as separate keyboard to configure

Tags: macos, keyboard, display, usb, mojave

MBP 14,1 (13" 2017 two TB ports)

At work I have a Dell USB-C dock that my external keyboard connects to - display is connected differently. There, like everywhere else I've seen this, when I connect an external (normal PC) keyboard it asks me to identify it ("press the key next to shift") and after that I can configure the external keyboard separately from the internal one (I like to switch alt+cmd on the PC layout).

I have a new LG screen (27UK850-W) at home that connects to the MBP via USB-C. It charges the device and transports display on that connection. The screen also has two USB-A ports - they work (I connect a mouse and my default external keyboard), but the keyboard doesn't show up as a "separate" device - if I remap the keys (alt+cmd in my case) this is also done for the built-in keyboard.

Any ideas how I can work around this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Modifier remap, in keyboard.prefPane exists a modifier button where you can edit it for external keyboard.
For more advanced ways, you should checkout keyboard Maestro for Macro keys and [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/133100/mousekeys-with-external-keyboard) to figure out what you want to do.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better/more complete than the others already provided.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review